# Oracle SQL Developer exporting only heading row when exporting data as delimited text file

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle9i

I am exporting the data fetched from select query as "Delimited Text file" but only the heading row gets exported and other rows are not exporting.

**Actual output:**

[image]

**Exported output exported file:**

[image]

Comment: version of sql dev? this is an oracle table that you're querying? the export dialog in the grid runs the query a 2nd time to get the data for the delimited text file

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - Often OP's don't notice what SO does with their tags... but I haven't seen the `oracle9i` tag added by SO by default; that may in fact be the OP picking the proper tag for their version. Which, then, might suggest a very old version of SQL Developer as well.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith The version is 9i even i tried with csv also getting the same issue

Comment: @madhan do this, should work even in your ancient software, in the sql worksheet, select /*csv*/ * from table; -- run with F5. depending on number of rows you might need to increase max script output size in preferences. but you REALLY need to upgrade your database.

Comment: @madhan, scroll to the right - is the data there? perhaps notepad isn't interpreting the linefeeds as carriage returns.